# Maximization of a determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, determinant

I'd like to compute
$$
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
A^*=\argmax_{\substack{A\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times k}\\A^T A=I}} \det(A^T \Lambda A)
$$
where $k\leq d$, $\Lambda=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_d)$ and $\lambda_1\geq\cdots\geq\lambda_d\geq0$.

I strongly suspect that $A^*=[\epsilon_1 \cdots \epsilon_k]$, but after various attempts to prove it I gave up.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio $\epsilon_1^T\epsilon_1=I_1$, but...

Comment: All right, but in such a case, isn't it enough to decompose $\Lambda$ as $M^T M$ (if possible)?

Comment: Are the eigenvalues on the main diagonal of $\Lambda$ nonnegative?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: even if not, we may consider a complex Cholesky decomposition.

Comment: This should only work if the $\lambda_i$ are non-negative.  I strongly suspect that the [min-max theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem) will help.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes, $\lambda_d\geq0$. Sorry!

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, I fixed my question. I'll look into the min-max theorem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $A$ has orthonormal columns, its singular value decomposition must be in the form of $A=U\pmatrix{I\\ 0}V^T$. Hence to maximise $\det(A^T\Lambda A)$ is equivalent to maximise the determinant of $P_k$, the $k\times k$ leading principal submatrix of $P=U^T\Lambda U$. However, by the interlacing property, the $i$-th largest eigenvalue of $P_k$ is bounded above by the $i$-th largest eigenvalue of $P$. Since $P$ and $U$ have identical spectra, it follows that $\det P_k\le\lambda_1\cdots\lambda_k$. Therefore $U=I$ is a maximiser and in turn, every $A=\pmatrix{I\\ 0}V^T$ is a maximiser whenever $V\in O_k(\mathbb R)$.